# Text validation in Windows form

Tags: .net

Anyone please help, for text validation.
One field will be input for one Id.
Id should be "N######" where # is numbers.
Please let me know how to put it under validation when button is clicked.

Comment: you can **use regular expression** like, `^[Nn]+[\d]+$`

Comment: Handle the control's `Validating` event.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[Nn]+[\d]+$"))
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid input");
         return;
    }
}
```